# Deleting item from 'dict_keyiterator'

Tags: python, iterator, networkx, iterable

I have been working with Networkx 1.10 but I updated it to version 2.2, I am having problem removing an item in a 'dict_keyiterator' which comes from G.neighbors.

In Networkx 1.10 to remove a item was easy because this: G.neighbors, was a list. But in this new version is an iterable.

If someone can help me, I really appreciate it! :)

This is what I have with Networkx 1.10:

```
        neighbors = G.neighbors(node)
        if parent is not None:
            neighbors.remove(parent)
```

But now, I can´t use remove. How can I remove the variable parent from neighbors if it is a dict_keyiterator?

Comment: materialize the iterator, into a list for example: `neighbors = list(G.neighbors(node))`

Comment: Thank you very much! It works!